# npm install error : Not found "logger-nodejs@1.0.11"

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run "npm install" in my project but npm keeps on showing me

> npm ERR! 404 Not Found: logger-nodejs@^1.0.11

same as for these items :

> restify-nodejs, metrics-nodejs

I'm confused cause it seems to happen only with "xxxx-nodejs" required items.

Here's the list of required items in my index.js:

```
const loggers = require('logger-nodejs');
const waterfall = require('async/waterfall');
const waterfall = require('async/waterfall');
const config = require('config');
const Server = require('restify-nodejs').Server;
const restify = require('restify');
const metrics = require('metrics-nodejs');
const bootstrap = require('./src/bootstrap');
const name = require('./package.json').name;
const routes = require('./src/routes');
const logger = require('./src/utility/logger').logger;
const auditLogger = require('./src/utility/logger').auditLogger;
```

package.json file.

```
enter code here
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "0.0.19",
  "description": "xxxxxx description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "xxxhh",
  "license": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.5",
    "config": "^1.24.0",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.2",
    "logger-nodejs": "^1.0.11",
    "metrics-nodejs": "^0.1.0",
    "node-cleanup": "^2.1.2",
    "object-mapper": "^3.0.1",
    "openid-client": "^1.12.0",
    "prom-client": "^10.0.2",
    "properties": "^1.2.1",
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "restify": "^5.0.1",
    "restify-nodejs": "^2.0.0",
    "restify-plugins": "^1.6.0",
    "restify-swagger-jsdoc": "^1.1.2",
    "splunk-bunyan-logger": "^0.9.2",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "uuid-parse": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "oracledb": "1.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "mock-require": "^2.0.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "contrast": "node index.js",
    "debug": "node-debug index.js",
    "test": "mocha --recursive",
    "test-debug": "mocha --recursive --debug-brk",
    "coverage": "istanbul cover --include-all-sources node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --recursive",
    "install-private": "npm install --registry http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share package.json file as well.

Comment: Hello Pankaj. I edited my post to reflect the json file.

Thanks you so much.

Comment: How did those packages get added to `package.json`? They don't exist.

Comment: I do not know as well. im just trying to run the project locally. i tried deleting those package in package.json. 
and presented me with a new error in config.js Error: cannot parse file, looked into the file; the file reads "default.properties" and in the error line inside config.js I noticed that there is no ".properties" extension supported, maybe thats why its throwing error.

Comment: Is this a work project? Can you ask someone else where those packages came from?

Comment: Hello. I just found out that those package were custom made. Thats why I im having a not found error in npm. So i reached out to the project author and personally ask about these packages. Thanks for the effort guys..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"logger-nodejs" is not such npm package.

Package name may be logging-nodejs.
Same with your "restify-nodejs".

You can check from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logging-nodejs)

**So you can check available package for nodejs on https://npmjs.com.**

Note: There may be the case that previously these package exist on npm but package owner removed.

Comment: Hello pankaj. Yeah your right. Those package were custom made, thats why its not available in npm.. solved it by reaching out to the project author and ask for the packages.